# Screensaver won't start in windows 8

Tags: windows, mouse, screensaver, windows-8

I had windows 7 on my computer for some times, I decided to install windows 8.  Had no problem with windows 7 with the same hardware.  But now the screensaver won't start.  Even if I set it to start after 1 minute.  I have a wireless mouse and a wired keyboard.

Comment: What happens if you try to preview the screensaver and don't move the mouse?

Comment: It works, the screensaver appears correctly with the preview button.  It just doesn't start by itself without the preview button.

Answer (score 1):

This may be because Windows is set up to sleep (or suspend) after a given amount of time. In this mode, the computer is kept in a "standby" state, not processing information or, in this case, rendering the screensaver.

As such, I recommend you to either disable or lengthen this time, by doing the following:

> Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options - Change when computer sleeps

Adjust to at least 30 minutes or never. This should allow the screensaver to show.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, certain mouse/keyboard's will do this without the proper drivers installed. Does this still happen if you unplug your mouse/keyboard and let the computer go into the screensaver?